# SQL Server 2012 : filtered index with "or" condition

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, filtered-index

I have SQL Server 2012 Standard and a table with a column `[IS_Deleted]`.

How I can create a filtered index with a condition?

```
    where [IS_Deleted] is null or [IS_Deleted] = 0
```

Comment: OR is not allowed in the filtered index definition, I believe you'd have to create 2 indexes to satisfy this condition

Comment: Sadly, this cannot be done with a filtered index on a computed column either.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say you cannot do this. See[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx#Restrictions) for details.

Consider using an indexed view instead as discussed by Arshad Ali on [MSSQLTips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1785/sql-server-filtered-indexes-what-they-are-how-to-use-and-performance-advantages/)

```
CREATE VIEW OnlyNotDeleted AS (    
 ...
 WHERE ISNULL(IS_Deleted,0)=0
)
```

Then index the appropriate field(s) on the view.

Answer (score 0):

As another option you can create a computed column and the index by this column.

```
create table tst10 (
    id int,
    f int
)

insert into tst10(id, f) values (1, 0)  
insert into tst10(id, f) values (2, 1)
insert into tst10(id) values (3)

select * from tst10

alter table tst10
add dummyColumn as ISNULL(f, 0)

select * from tst10

create index dummyColumnIdx on tst10(dummyColumn)
```